# how to remove id password in sql user i have done it what thing i have to see for this

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
//SqlConnection myConnectionSave1 = new SqlConnection("server=" + DbServer + ";uid=" + DbUid + ";pwd=" + DbPwd + ";database=" + Db + "");
SqlConnection myConnectionSave1 = new SqlConnection("server=" + DbServer + ";database=" + Db + ";Intergrated Security=true");
```

I have change all the connection like this, and still it is not running it shows me this error which is in picture. Please tell me what i have to change in connection string.
[image: this is the error]

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: You should specify the user and his password to access the DbServer

Comment: You're going to have to provide the full exception message and the inner exception (if there is one). A screenshot isn't enough. Does your windows account have access to the database?

Comment: what is "id password"?

Comment: Search your project for "sa1". You most likely still have a reference to sa1 as the UID somewhere.

Comment: What's in your web.config? That might still have a connection string that is being referenced at the application startup.